# Unexpected results from custom partitioning scheme - Ubuntu preseed unattended install

Tags: linux, installation, partition, unattended

I need some help with partman-auto custom recipe in preseed.... it's doing unexpected things, the docs aren't so clear.

This is in my preseed file:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                     \
  boot-root-var ::                                        \
          1024 100 1024 ext4                               \
                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
          .                                               \
          2048  50 4096 ext4                              \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .                                               \
          4096  25 100000 ext4                            \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /var }                      \
          .                                               \
           256  75 100% linux-swap                        \
                  method{ swap } format{ }                \
          .
```

Given an 80GB drive. I ended up with these partitions:

```
/     2GB
/boot 1GB
/var  4GB
swap  72GB
```

What went wrong? What I want is:

```
/     2GB
/boot 1GB
/var  72GB
swap  4GB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this recipe:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                     \
  boot-root-var ::                                        \
          1024 1024 1024 ext3                             \
                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
          .                                               \
          2048  2048 4096 ext3                            \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .                                               \
          4096  4096 -1 ext3                              \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ /var }                      \
          .                                               \
           256  4096 4096 linux-swap                      \
                  method{ swap } format{ }                \
          .
```

You can find the documentation for these recipes in [devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=d-i/debian-installer.git;a=blob;f=doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt), but honestly: these partitioning recipes in preseed files are a real pain compared to Kickstart files or `setup-storage` from FAI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a very similar issue and as of yet have not been able to resolve it.  All I want is for my swap partition to end up as the size I've defined.

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              200 3000 300 ext2                               \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              -l 100 -1 ext3                                  \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              2048 200 2048 linux-swap                        \
                      $lvmok{ }                               \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .

This should result in a swap of 2GB, but instead ends up at nearly 6GB.  Before I got to using this current recipe (a few tweaks prior) I once had a 227GB swap partition!  My recipe should be creating the swap second to boot, with a size of 2048MB (to the nearest cylinder).

Comment: This is an additional question, not an answer.